# Javascript multiple media queries doesn't work

Tags: javascript, media-queries

Somebody made this code for me online but it doesn't work. It still goes through the 2 other codes so when you click it goes through the first media query code then the second and then sometimes also the third. How can this be fixed. This is very important for me because i have a only one page website which is scrollable through the whole page. And we all know mobile users are the highest rate of users. So i really hope someone can fix this for me and explain me why this version isn't working.

Help is really really appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function mediaSize() {
        var isTabletLandscape = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape)');
        var isPhoneLandscape = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: landscape)');
        var isPhonePortrait = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: portrait)');
        if (isTabletLandscape.matches) {
            //code for tablet landscape
            $('#menu ul li #page3').on('click', function(){
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top  * 0.78}, 850);
            });
        } else if (isPhoneLandscape.matches) {
            //code for phone landscape
            $('#menu ul li #page3').on('click', function(){
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top  * 0.89}, 850);
            });
        } else if (isPhonePortrait.matches) {
            //code for phone portrait
            $('#menu ul li #page3').on('click', function(){
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top  * 0.69}, 850);
            });
        } else {
            //code for desktop
            $('#menu ul li #page3').on('click', function(){
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top  * 0.99}, 850);
            });
        }   
    }
    mediaSize();

    window.addEventListener('resize', mediaSize, false);
});
```

Comment: So someone wrote this code for you, and now you're going back online to get someone else to modify it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `mediaSize()` it's attaching a new click event listener.  And this one, because it fires continuously while the window is being resized, adds a whole *boatload* of listeners:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', mediaSize, false);
```

(You asked me in comments to explain that further: the resize event fires continuously the whole time the user is resizing the window. So while the user is dragging the window borders around, the browser is calling mediaSize over and over, setting probably hundreds of duplicate event handlers on the same element.)

One solution would be to cancel existing listeners using `off()` before setting a new one. It would be simpler, though, to only attach a single listener and have it respond to the current screen size, instead of constantly replacing listeners with slightly different ones whenever the screen size changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // $('#menu ul li #page3') is unnecessarily complicated. IDs are unique, so all you need is #page3
  $('#page3').on('click', function() {
    // personally I'd check window.innerWidth here instead, but if this works, great:
    var isTabletLandscape = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1366px) and (orientation: landscape)');
    var isPhoneLandscape = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: landscape)');
    var isPhonePortrait = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 812px) and (orientation: portrait)');

    // you're doing the same thing in all of these conditions, except for the
    // number you're multiplying offset.top by, so let's just set 
    // that as a variable here:
    var multiple = 0.99;
    if (isTabletLandscape.matches) {
      multiple = 0.78;
    } else if (isPhoneLandscape.matches) {
      multiple = 0.89
    } else if (isPhonePortrait.matches) {
      multiple = 0.69;
    }

    // and now we only need to have one 'animate' block:
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".footer").offset().top * multiple
    }, 850);
  })
});
```

This way you don't need to bother rebinding anything on window resize; the function will check the screen size only when it needs to.

Comment: Thanks for your time! But when it still goes to the desktop version first. To check if i did the correct thing i changed `var multiple = 0.6;
    if (isTabletLandscape.matches) {
      multiple = 0.6;
    } else if (isPhoneLandscape.matches) {
      multiple = 0.6;
    } else if (isPhonePortrait.matches) {
      multiple = 0.6;
    }` 
it to this.

I have the desktop code above `$(document).ready(function() {` . I don't know if that is correct? If not where should i put all my desktop code. Sorry for the stupid questions but my knowledge for Javascript is just beginning.

Comment: And i didn't use `indow.addEventListener('resize', mediaSize, false);` Don't know exactly what you mean with that. More details please

Comment: By "goes to the desktop version first" do you mean on page load?  If so, that's because this function only runs after a user click...

Comment: Nevermind it works! I forgot to remove the desktop code above that code you made for me. I am so gratefull for your time and it is perfect because i only have to adjust some little things. So your solution is more then perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$('#menu ul li #page3').off();` for stop listeners

Comment: Should i do that in the desktop version code because then the scroll function doesn't work or should i put it inside the javascript code that Daniel Beck made